# Translate for loop into parallel foreach loop in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I try to optimize parts of a simulation script and have parts of it run in parallel. So I discovered the `foreach` function.
As an example I try to have the following run in parallel

```
Wiederholungen<-4
assign("A",array(0,c(Wiederholungen,10,3)))
assign("B",array(0,c(Wiederholungen,10,3)))
assign("C",array(0,c(Wiederholungen,10,3)))
```

**Old Code:**

```
for(m in 1:Wiederholungen){
  A[m,,]<-m

  B[m,,]<-m

  C[m,,]<-m
}
```

Resulting in: (for A)

```
A
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
```

This should put the value of m in the m-th row of the dataframes `A,B & C`. In my script m is the number of replicates (Wiederholungen) the script should run.

**Foreach Code:**

```
foreach(m=1:Wiederholungen)%dopar%{
    A[m,,]<-m

    B[m,,]<-m

    C[m,,]<-m
}
```

Resulting in:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

But this does not lead in the above result for the dataframes `A,B,C`. I know that `foreach` has a `combine` option but it seems only to work if you have the result for one matrix and not for several as in my example. How do I get the same result as with my old for loop using a parallel processing approach. I am using Ubuntu and 3.2.2.

Comment: what is displayed is not the values of A, B and C. Type `A` and you will have what you want

Comment: If I type A it prints out the matrix A wit only zeros as assigned in the first step.

Comment: I haven't got this, the assignment works well for me. Are your packages / R version up to date ?

Comment: I am using R version 3.2 and foreach 1.4.2. I don't see foreach to write the data to the matrices.

Comment: This is not how a `foreach` loop works. You should study the vignettes. In brief, return the results from each iteration (like you would with a function) and combine the results using a function passed to `.combine` or in a subsequent step.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but thought an answer might help someone in the future.

Foreach returns a list of only the last object created in the loop. so if you want A, B, and C returned you need to list them as the final step of the loop.
This code works for me.

```
W<- foreach(m = 1:Wiederholungen) %dopar% {

A[m,,]<-m

B[m,,]<-m

C[m,,]<-m

list(A, B, C)
}
```

For future reference, the foreach vignette can be very helpful with things like this.